# how to reverse the textbox input method in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have used a code like this

```
EPF_NO.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Now EPF_NO text box is showing `***` like that and I'm okay with that.
but I need to get it to normal mode when I clicked on a radio button.

Comment: You must provide more code if you want us to help you. Please providee focused and specific code and more explicit example of what is the problem

Comment: Are you looking to show the password on the Click of the Radio Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `EPF_NO.PasswordChar = '\0';`

Comment: @kaushmilove Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the property to default '0'

```
if (toggleSwitch1.IsOn)
{
    string a = EPF_NO.Text;
    EPF_NO.PasswordChar = '\0';
}
else
{
    EPF_NO.PasswordChar = '*';
}
```

Comment: `if (toggleSwitch1.IsOn==true)` why not `if(toggleSwitch1.IsOn)`?

Answer (score 1):

Eh, something like that?

```
EPF_NO.PasswordChar = showPlainTextRadioButton.Checked ? '\0' : '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in `Radio button` click event

```
   private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked) { textBox1.PasswordChar='\0';  }
        else { textBox1.PasswordChar = '*'; }
    }
```

Comment: no it is not doing the job. it will show nothing when i do that.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
EPF_NO.PasswordChar = '\0';
EPF_NO.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
```